# How do I add multiple values inside a marker? (PDO execute)

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to put multiple values inside the SQL **IN** operator with the PDO execute function in my query, but it seems like it doesn't work with what I've tried and doesn't return anything:

```
// FETCH GAMES TABLE
$allGames = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `video_games` WHERE `console` IN (:consoles) ORDER BY `price` DESC");
$consolesQuery = ["PS5", "PC", "NES"];
$allGames->execute([
    ":consoles" => implode(", ", $consolesQuery)
]);
```

It works only when I put one value inside the `$consoleQuery` array, but with additionnal values it won't work. Is there a better solution for it? Thank you!

Comment: What you mean by additionnal values? What you show here should work...

Comment: For example when I only keep "PS5" in the $consolesQuery, it works, but with multiple it won't.